# How do I access a JSON object using a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json

What I mean by that is say I have JSON data as such:

```
[{"ADAM":{"TEST":1}, "BOBBY":{"TEST":2}}]
```

and I want to do something like this:

```
var x = "ADAM";
alert(data.x.TEST);
```

Comment: you have to loop through them because I guess adam/bobby is not static. Something like data[i].x.TEST

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var data = [{"ADAM":{"TEST":1}, "BOBBY":{"TEST":2}}],
    x = "ADAM";

alert(data[0][x].TEST);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n0nick/UWR9y/

Answer (score 5):

Since objects in javascripts are handled just like hashmaps (or associative arrays) you can just do data['adam'].TEST just like you could do data.adam.TEST. If you have a variable index, just go with the [] notation.

```
var data = [{"ADAM":{"TEST":1}, "BOBBY":{"TEST":2}}]
alert(data[0].ADAM.TEST);
alert(data[0]['ADAM'].TEST)
```

if you just do

```
var data = {"ADAM":{"TEST":1}, "BOBBY":{"TEST":2}};
```

you could access it using data.ADAM.TEST and data['ADAM'].TEST

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as you're setting `x` to be a string object, no accessing the value from your array:

```
alert(data[0]["ADAM"].TEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = [{"ADAM":{"TEST":1}, "BOBBY":{"TEST":2}}],
 x = "ADAM";

alert(data[x].TEST);
```

This is what worked for me.  This way you can pass in a variable to the function and avoid repeating you code.

```
function yourFunction(varName, elementName){
//json GET code setup
document.getElementById(elementName).innerHTML = data[varName].key1 + " " + data.[varName].key2;
}
```