# Fetching data from a json file using variables javascript

Tags: javascript, json

My question is pretty simple. I have a json file stored and I fetch it using a simple xml request and store it for later use in the `localstorage`. Now What I need to do is that when the user selects something from the select tag, I fetch the value of the tag and use it get the data from json.

For ex:

```
database.Class.Teachers."The value from the select tag".age
```

Is this possible with javascript or similar workaround?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what you are asking, but I think you are trying to access a property of an object by name. You can use brackets for that. `database.Class.Teachchers[valueFromSelect]`. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're saying that you are able to retrieve the JSON using simple XML request, then the only challenge is retrieving the tag value from the fetched JSON and to do that, I'd say you need to have your JSON structured like {"tag_value":{}}...like a dictionary.

Comment: It's possible, but why would you do it, why not just store the JSON as a regular object in your javascript file and use it directly ?

Comment: Aviv, thanks thats exactly what i wanted. Sayed, thanks that helped. adeneo I am doing that, i am using the localstorage provided by the browser. unless i am wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the answer. Thanks.

link for the working code i found.
[How do I access a JSON object using a javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010309/how-do-i-access-a-json-object-using-a-javascript-variable)